# 2008 Grand Prix GPX

Tags: ignition, sparkplugs, pontiac, grand-prix

What spark plug should I be using?

I did my own tune up and the guy at auto advance told me to get some Bosch spark plugs for my car but then I notice less power. A mechanic told me I shouldn't have bought them.

So can you please help me please?

Answer (score 4):

Mitchell shows original equipment plugs are ACDelco 41-962 for the 5.3, which are double platinum plugs. Plug gap is 0.040".

I've never used nor sold Bosch plugs before. From talking to people, I've never heard anything good.

Make sure the plug gap is correct and that the wires are fully seated. If you still feel that the car is not performing as well as it was. Try buying different plugs. It may also be a good time to change the spark plug wires if you haven't yet.